# How to use cookies in i18next configuration?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I want to use react-cookie in my i18n.js file to set a language.

I was trying like this, but it send this error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```js
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import i18n from 'i18next'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import * as en from './locales/en.json'
import * as pl from './locales/pl.json'
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie'

const { cookies } = useCookies(['i18n_locale'])

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en.default
  },
  "pl-PL": {
    translation: pl.default
  }
}

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: cookies.i18n_locale ? cookies.i18n_locale : window.navigator.language,
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  })

export default useCookies(i18n)
```

I want it working!

Answer (score -1):

React hooks have certain rules associated with their use ([see this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)). One of them is mentioned right there in the error message:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Regarding `react-cookie` usage: first off, wrap your root element in the provider component. This will allow invoking `useCookies` down the tree in any function-based component. Check out [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie#simple-example-with-react-hooks) from lib's docs.